# LARAVEL Payload is invalid error but decrypted data is correct

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, payload, mutators

Recently i made new project with composer and added very basic authentication with make:auth - nothing fancy.

Next i wanted to encrypt **name** and **email** columns on my database so i changed their types from VARCHAR(191) to LONGTEXT and added some very basic mutators to Users model

```
public function setNameAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['name'] = Crypt::encryptString($value);
}

public function getNameAttribute($value) {
    return Crypt::decryptString($value);
}

public function setEmailAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['email'] = Crypt::encryptString($value);
}

public function getEmailAttribute($value) {
    return Crypt::decryptString($value);
}
```

But when im testing with my very simple route i get Payload is invalid error even though i see in error contents that fields has been decrypted properly.

```
Route::get('user',function(){
$user= \App\User::find(3);
//dd($user->name);
dd(Crypt::decryptString($user->name));
dd(Crypt::decryptString($user->email));
```

});

Screenshot link
https://ibb.co/deBPpR

Comment: what does `dd($user->name);` print?

Comment: Yes, to see raw value, thats why its commented out for now.

Comment: What raw value?

Comment: RAW = not encrypted, stright from the the database. Are you familiar with Laravel??

Comment: I live and breathe Laravel, The error is because you are trying to decrypt an already decrypted string. Please see my answer

Comment: @SapneshNaik or an __empty__ `String` which caused a similar issue on my end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is because **you are calling `Crypt::decryptString` on an already mutated (and decrypted) name property**. i.e your `getNameAttribute` decrypts the encrypted string and when you call

```
Crypt::decryptString($user->name); // this is causing the error
```

You basically pass a decrypted string for decryption again.

**Just do:**

```
echo $user->name;
```

and you will get the decrypted name.

**If you really want to see the raw value then use:**

```
echo $user->getOriginal('name'); //get original value from DB bypassing the accessor
```

Comment: OMG its so stupid mistake that im even embarassed. Thank you! However this testing script was only for testing if encryption/decryption is going well. My bigger problem is that when i make new user i cant login with it. I will try debug this deeper and if i will not solve it then ill throw a topic here. Thanks again.

Comment: @180doman No problem, happens to the best of us. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

**Payload is invalid** is also the response I get when I try to decrypt a null value. Make sure to catch null values before decrypting.